# Ionisation energy

Tags: atoms

**Explain why the 1st ionization energy of boron is less than that of beryllium, whereas the 2nd ionization energy of boron is greater than that of beryllium.**

Answer (score 1):

***First ionisation enegy*** 
of Beryllium is 900 Kilojoules per mole and that of Boron is 801 Kj/mole, you must be confused by the trend of periodic table in which the size of the atom gets smaller when going from left to right in a period due the force of the Positive nucleus so how can the i energy of Beryllium be more than Boron? 
But we are thinking in terms of orbitals now, the game is changed a little bit. The reason is due to their electronic configuration..

Electronic configuration of Beryllium is 1s2 2s2(since the orbitals are filled completely, its going to become stable and when an atom is stable..it is very hard to remove an electron from it and disturb its stability).

Electronic configuration of Boron is 1s2 2s1 2p1(Since the last p orbital is not filled completely then its going to stay unstable and also, the energy of p orbital is higher than s orbitals so its going to be pretty easy to remove an electron from it and make it stable when its configuration will be 1s2 2s1- like Beryllium, stable).
**Second ionization energy**
After removing the valency electron during first ionisation, you get the following configurations
Beryllium : 1s² 2s¹ 
Boron: 1s² 2s²

As you can see, Beryllium has less electrons left in its valency shell that Boron has, so the nuclear effect (postitive charge) will have a greater influence on that electron, pulling the entire shell closer, and reducing the ionic radius. When the shell gets closer to the nucleus, it becomes harder to remove an electron from the lower energy level "2s¹" because of the very strong attractive forces between the electrons and the nucleus thus requiring lots of energy. In Boron's case, although there is one electron less than before, and there is now a full sub-shell "2s²", the shielding effect of the inner shells repel the outer two electrons causing the ionic radius to be greater than that of Beryllium, and thus needing less energy to over come to electrostatic attraction between the nucleus and the valency electron.